# How can I complete my current query about User Defined Table Types and getting Schema,IsIdentity,IsPrimaryKey and ...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-types

I have a query for getting information about User Defined Table Types.

I need to complete this query by adding the following columns :

```
IsIdentity
IsPrimaryKey
Schema
ColumnDefaultValue
```

The query:

```
SELECT  o.name AS TableName ,
        c.name AS ColumnName ,
        c.isnullable AS [IsNullable] ,
        t.name AS [DataType] ,
        t.[length] AS [MaxLength] ,
        t.prec AS [Precision]
FROM    syscolumns c
        INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN systypes t ON t.xtype = c.xtype
WHERE   c.id IN ( SELECT    type_table_object_id
                  FROM      sys.table_types )
ORDER BY o.name ,
        c.name;
```

And I have another question about the above query.

I have User Defined Table Types with `dbo.MyType` as name but in this query it shows me 'TT_MyType_37C5420D'.

How can I get the real name ?

Comment: In SQL Server **2005** and newer, you should use the `sys` schema, like `sys.columns` instead of `syscolumns` (and the same applies to `sys.tables`, `sys.types` etc.)

Comment: @marc_s Can you rewrite my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new catalog views from the `sys` schema as of SQL Server **2005** and avoid the old `syscolumns`, `sysobjects` etc.

When rewriting your query to this:

```
SELECT  
    tt.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS ColumnName,
    c.is_nullable AS [IsNullable],
    c.is_identity,
    t.name AS [DataType],
    t.max_length [MaxLength],
    t.precision AS [Precision]
FROM
    sys.table_types tt
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
ORDER BY 
    tt.name, c.name;
```

you can easily tap into the more extensive information available in the `sys` catalog view - like the `c.is_identity` column on `sys.columns`. And also - the `name` from `sys.table_types` seems to return the more humanly readable name as you were looking for.

Check out the [**very extensive** MSDN documentation on the `sys` catalog views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) do discover a lot more information you might be interested in